# Generate text box

Tags: php, javascript

How do I generate n number of input text box in JavaScript using a select option. And how do I fetch the variables in PHP.

below is my html form

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Dynamically add Textbox in html Form using JavaScript</TITLE>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
            var numberOfElementsAdded;
            var arrayOfInputs = new Array();
            function addToDatabase(numberOfElementsAdded) {
                numberOfElementsAdded = numberOfElementsAdded * numberOfElementsAdded;
                var alltext = "";
                for (var j = 1; j <= numberOfElementsAdded; j++) {
                    var tvalue = document.getElementsByName("text" + j)[0].value;
                    arrayOfInputs.push(tvalue);
                    alltext = alltext + tvalue + " ";
                }
                alert(alltext);
            }

            function add(type, num) {
                numberOfElementsAdded = num;
                //Create an input type dynamically.
                var k = 0;
                for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        var element = document.createElement("input");
                        k = k + 1;
                        //Assign different attributes to the element.
                        element.setAttribute("type", type + k);
                        element.setAttribute("id", type + k);
                        element.setAttribute("name", type + k);
                        element.setAttribute('width', '30');
                        element.setAttribute('border', '3px solid #FF0000');

                        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
                        //Append the element in page (in span).
                        foo.appendChild(element);
                    }
                    var breakLoop = document.createElement('br')
                    foo.appendChild(breakLoop)
                }
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                element.setAttribute("type", "button");
                element.setAttribute("id", "Submit");
                element.setAttribute("name", "Insert into database");
                element.setAttribute("value", "Insert into database");
                element.setAttribute("onclick", "addToDatabase(numberOfElementsAdded)");
                var breakLoop = document.createElement('br')
                foo.appendChild(breakLoop)
                foo.appendChild(element);
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM>
        <H2>Dynamically add element in form.</H2>
        <SELECT name="element">
            <OPTION value="1">1</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="2">2</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="3">3</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="4">4</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="5">5</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="6">6</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="7">7</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="8">8</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="9">9</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="10">10</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add('text',document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
        <BR/>
        <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

It generates the text box. But I want to fetch the values of text box as a PHP variable.

Comment: Read about AJAX: http://tech.pro/tutorial/791/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code generates the textboxes properly, to get the values in PHP, you will have to amend this:

```
element.setAttribute("name", "Insert into database");
```

to

```
element.setAttribute("name", "myFieldName[]"); // with the [] brackets
```

Then in PHP, you will get it this way:

```
$fields = $_POST['myFieldName'];

// make it into a single delimited field
$fields = implode('|', $fields);
```